# Wordpress Third Level Menu Custom Walker

Tags: wordpress

I am looking to change Custom walker for wordpress in a way that (only for third level menu items( every 2 LI (menu item) gets wrapped within a NEW  currently wordpress creates a html structure like.

What I am trying to achieve is grouping of menu so I can make menu more representable using html and css

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="" title="Level 1">level 1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li>
         <a href="" title="Level 2">level 2</a>
           <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li><a href="" title="Level A">ITEM A</a></li>
             <li><a href="" title="Level B">ITEM B</a></li>
             <li><a href="" title="Level C">ITEM C</a></li>
             <li><a href="" title="Level D">ITEM D</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Php walker Function what I have made for now

```
class Description_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {


function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        // depth dependent classes
        $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
        $display_depth = ( $depth); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
        $classes = array('sub-menu','level-' . $display_depth);
        $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );
    $add_markup = "<div class='sub-menu-wrapper'>";

    // build html
        $output .= "\n" . $indent . $add_markup . '<ul class="' . $class_names . '">' . "\n";

}

function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $classes     = empty ( $item->classes ) ? array () : (array) $item->classes;
        $immediateCls   =   "commonClsFirst";
        $class_names = join(
            ' '
        ,   apply_filters(
                'nav_menu_css_class'
            ,   array_filter( $classes ), $item
            )
        );
        if(@$args->has_children){
            $downarrow  =   '<button class="mobileOnly down-mcaret"> <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></button>';
        }
        if(@$args->has_children && $depth > 0){
            $immediateCls   =   "commonClsFirst downLevelAfter";
        }
        if (@$args->has_children && $depth == 0){
        ! empty ( $class_names )
            and $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . ' has_children"';
        }
        else{
         ! empty ( $class_names )
            and $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';  
        }
        // $menuId   = $args->menu->term_id;
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';
        $output .= "<li $id $class_names>" ;
        $attributes  = '';

        ! empty( $item->attr_title )
            and $attributes .= ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->target )
            and $attributes .= ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->xfn )
            and $attributes .= ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->url )
            and $attributes .= ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"';

        // insert description for top level elements only
        // you may change this
        $description = ( ! empty ( $item->description ) and 0 == $depth )
            ? '<span class="desc">' . esc_attr( $item->description ) . '</span>' : '';

        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
        if ( $depth == 0 ) {//top level items
            $item_output = @$args->before
            . "<a class='commonClsFirst first-level menuCls".$item->ID."' $attributes>"
            . @$args->link_before
            . $title
            . '</a>'
            . @$args->link_after
            . @$downarrow
            . @$description
            . @$args->after;
        }else{//everything else
        $item_output = $args->before
            . "<div class='anchor__button'><a class='$immediateCls multi-level menuCls".$item->ID."' $attributes>"
            . @$args->link_before
            . $title
            . '</a> '
            . @$args->link_after
            . @$downarrow
            . "</div>"
            . @$args->after;
        }
        // Since $output is called by reference we don't need to return anything.
        $output .= apply_filters(
            'walker_nav_menu_start_el'
        ,   $item_output
        ,   $item
        ,   $depth
        ,   $args
        , $id
        );

}

// Displays end of a level. E.g '</ul>'
// @see Walker::end_lvl()
function end_lvl(&$output, $depth=0, $args=array()) {
  $display_depth = ( $depth); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
  $add_markup = "</div>";
  $output .= "</ul>\n".$add_markup."\n";
}

function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {
    //v($element);
    if ( !$element )
    return;

    $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];

    //display this element
    if ( is_array( $args[0] ) )
    $args[0]['has_children'] = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
    else if ( is_object( $args[0] ) )
    $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
    $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);
    call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'start_el'), $cb_args);

    $id = $element->$id_field;

    // descend only when the depth is right and there are childrens for this element
    if ( ($max_depth == 0 || $max_depth > $depth+1 ) && isset( $children_elements[$id]) ) {

    foreach( $children_elements[ $id ] as $child ){

    if ( !isset($newlevel) ) {
    $newlevel = true;
    //start the child delimiter
    $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $depth), $args);
    call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'start_lvl'), $cb_args);
    }
    $this->display_element( $child, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth + 1, $args, $output );
    }
    unset( $children_elements[ $id ] );
    }

    if ( isset($newlevel) && $newlevel ){
    //end the child delimiter
    $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $depth), $args);
    call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'end_lvl'), $cb_args);
    }

    //end this element
    $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);
    call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'end_el'), $cb_args);

    }
}
```